# Executing a jar with version in shell script

Tags: java, shell, jar

I am trying to build an executable jar file with version[which includes mainfest with main class].
ie) `testjar-2.0.jar`

I am writing a script to launch the jar with complete package name it works fine and it will be helpful in future if i change the version of jar

```
ie) com.java.test.TestMain
```

Since it is an executable with version i thought using the below command will no longer use in future.

```
ie) java -jar testjar-2.0.jar`
```

In future there may be change of version in jar if you are using the hardcoded version in script. What would be the optimised way? is there any other way better way?

Comment: Potentially but this isn't really Java related. You probably want to look for "How to find/run a file in linux using a file and wildcard" here is a head start [How can I get the first match from wildcard expansion?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156205/how-can-i-get-the-first-match-from-wildcard-expansion)

Answer (score 2):

Here are some ideas:

- Generate the shell script with the version number by substituting into a template; e.g. in the installer, or when building the artifacts to go into the installer.
- Rename the JAR file to a name that doesn't have the version number in it.
- Create a symbolic for the JAR without the version number that points to the JAR file with the version number.  Then write the script to use the symlink.
- Write the script "globbing" to match the JAR file; e.g.

  ```
  java -jar testjar-*.jar
  ```

Comment: I would agree Stephen. is there any performance impact? Also we jar which i am using is a 3pp jar that's i am using the complete namespace to execute the jar application

Comment: 1) No.  2) No.  3) Minimal. 4) Minimal.  In the minimal cases, the overhead will be milliseconds, compared with seconds to start the JVM.

Comment: Sorry?  You are comparing what ... with what?

Comment: Executing with jar file in script with executing with complete package name in script.

Comment: The difference is negligible.

Comment: Which one is faster?

Comment: Test it and see for yourself.  I predict that the difference is negligible ... and that you are wasting your time worrying about this.